# Which files do control XMonad’s startup in Mac's X11?

Tags: mac, startup, x11

My X11 crashes if I have the following .xinitrc

**My .xinitrc**

```
exec /Users/Masi/.cabal/bin/xmonad
```

I am not sure where the bug is.

Files which I know affects the startup are

1. ~/.cabal/bin/xmonad
2. (perhaps): ~/xmonad.hs
3. ~/.xinitrc

I have completed the steps in the [tutorial](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Using_xmonad_on_Apple_OSX).

**Which files do control XMonad's startup in Mac (Leopard)'s X11?**

Comment: What problem did theman's answer solve, and what problem is persisting?

Comment: @Clinton: We know now that the bug is in my .xinitrc -file. It seems that the problem is in XMonad in Mac. I have no idea where to debug. -- I have reinstalled the packages. -- This suggests me that the problem is a combability issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1. ~/.xinitrc
```

this guy gets called when you type "startx".  Mine looks like this:

```
exec /Users/theman/bin/dwm
```

I bet your problem is this file.  This is called when X starts.  dwm is my window manager, if that path doesnt exist, its trying to execute somethign that isnt there, and obviously will crash.  reply with your ~/.xinitrc

```
2. ~/.Xresources
```

not quite sure

```
3. ~/.Xmodmap
```

this is key bindings and such

```
4. ~/.Xsession
```

not quite sure

```
5. ~/.Xdefaults
```

this sets defaults, such as background color, for your terminal and/or other X apps

```
6. ~/.Xauthority
```

not quite sure to be honest

Also, what version os and X are you using?

Comment: @Theman: The problem is now in XMonad. It makes my Mac to X11 to crash.

Comment: @theman: Thank your for your answer! It solves the first problem in locating the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Do you get anything useful logs in `console`?

Comment: I added two log messages. The first process is being forced quit. I am sure why. Either it is me or an external program.

Answer (score 1):

[fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start) will let you see what files are in use, graphically.  (Try [fs_usage](http://rentzsch.com/macosx/fs_usageIntro) if you want a command-line app.)

One more file to look at is ~/Library/Preferences/org.x.X11.plist.

Comment: Is fseventer open-source? I could not find its source code.

Comment: fseventer is not open-source but it is donationware. (Freeware but he does ask for donations if you find it useful)